# A PHP object server for business logic

Tags: php

I wonder if such a thing is possible or even exist :

In the MVC pattern, I would like to have the Model part to be persistant in memory, instead of reloading my instances at each execution. So I want only the Controller and View part to be executed.

Is there any solution of server that would provide PHP objects (just like a Mysql server provides data records), and that keeps these objects in memory ?

A problem would be also : how to have a constructed query to get objects ? Maybe [PHP Linq](http://phplinq.codeplex.com/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the best solution would be to use an ORM solution like Doctrine, it handles cache in memory and all I need.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [APC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) and [XCache](http://xcache.lighttpd.net/wiki/Introduction). They enable you to keep any variable in memory between requests.

Comment: Nice, but I can't perform complicated queries on it (i have to go through a SQl request to know wich objects I want to get back)